# Is FTP is secured one in the .Net Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-2.0

I am using .Net FrameWork 2.0.In my application i want to transfer the messages to the server in a secure way.

1.For that, I formatted the messages and stored it in to string object.

2.now I'll send this string object to MQ.

3.There is a class which will read the string object from the MQ.

1. For transferring the message to Server,i am using the FTP in .Net 2.0. TCPClient and TCPListener are the 2 classes used for sending the messages to server as a File.

Is there any other Secured FTP transfer available in .Net 2.0?

Is anyother Protocol available in .Net 2.0 for transferring messages?

pls anyone guide me.

Comment: FTP is done in plain text, so no it's not secure.

Comment: @UpTheCreek : otherthan FTP ,tell me anyother secure way to transfer the messages to server as files

Answer (score 2):

SFTP (or SSH, on which SFTP is built) is not available out of the .NET box. You can use a third party library though:

[Here's a comparison of some of those libraries](http://www.sftp-net.com/sftp-compare.html).

[An here's another one](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html), [and another one](http://www.atp-inc.net/component/sftp.net/) which aren't in the above comparison.

Seems like there's no shortage on third party libraries on this regard...

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not being built in to the .NET Framework, there's an example of how you can do yourself on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FTP_Secure.aspx). I haven't used it myself though, so I can't vouch for its reliability.

Are you in control of the server as well? If you are then you might want to look at using WCF, or even a simple web page/MVC endpoint that you can post the file's data to. As long as you're doing it over an SSL connection the contents of the file will be encrypted during transport. You can build in as many or as few security mechanisms as you want then.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of secure data transfer options is quite wide and what you choose depends solely on what you want to accomplish and what your constraints are.

FTP itself is not secure, but there's FTP over TLS (FTPS), which is. FTPS involves X.509 certificates (sometimes called X.509 certificates). The certificates can be self-signed or signed by CA (the latter have greater credibility). Obviously you need to have an FTP/FTPS server on the other side.

Now there's SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol), which runs over SSH. SSH uses SSH keys for authentication (SSH can use X.509 certificates as well but not many servers and clients support this). SSH keys are not issued by CA, i.e. they are always self-generated. SFTP is a handy way to transfer the files securely, yet in highly secure environments SSH key management can become a weak link. There's no built-in support for SFTP in .NET Framework.

We should also mention HTTP over SSL/TLS (HTTPS), which is a simple way to transfer the data over HTTP. HTTPS support is built into .NET Framework, though there are certain minor shortcomings (mainly related to certificate management and validation) there.

All of the above require a protocol server application running on the server. So if you are limited in what you can / may install on the server, the choice depends on what you already have there.

There exist more rarely used security-enabled protocols such as WebDAV over TLS or AS2 and AS3, but they are more specific and not needed for your relatively simple needs.

Finally you can employ message encryption (using X.509 certificates or OpenPGP keys) and transfer the encrypted message via regular channels such as FTP or HTTP.

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) component suite offers both client-side and server-side components for all of the above mentioned protocols and technologies. This means that no matter what technology you choose for security-related tasks, SecureBlackbox will be helpful.